# Why is software testing so low ranked inside the development hierachy?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

Some things I have noticed from working as a QA Analyst for 1+ years:

- In the development team, the QA Analyst is the least respected. They are perceived as low skilled (manual testers) and are often ignored in time estimates.
- Some developers ignore the comments made by a QA Analyst and go directly to the product owner. If a QA Analyst complains about a specific feature, the product owner has ultimate authority over any complaint filed by the QA Analyst.
- Developers look down on all forms of manual testing.
- Manual testing is extremely boring and is not intellectually satisfying.
- Testers are treated more like resources who verify bugs/stories as opposed to doing coding (development) work.

As a tester, I am a reasonably hard worker. Some of the other testers that I work with watch Youtube videos at work and generally don't test well. I find bugs in development work for their projects. Do similar situations happen at other companies?

I don't want to become a developer and as a manual tester I am extremely bored. I am also fairly well educated and testing doesn't seem to use any of my analytical skills. I think I should get out of the software industry.

Comment: `> I don't want to become a developer and as a manual tester I am extremely bored. I am also fairly well educated and testing doesn't seem to use any of my analytical skills. I think I should get out of the software industry.`

I sympathize but this isn't a forum for venting your frustrations.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the situation you're in right now, but this question is in clear contrast of our [no rants policy](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). :-( Everyone here will agree that looking down on testers is complete bullshit but this question can't actionably help you with that.

Comment: Learn some adjacent skills: test automation; system administration; learn SQL and how to make SQL queries. You will be not a full scale developer but notch above pure manual tester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you are the one that should take attitude.

Discuss this with the QA team, research and do your best to make a difference.
Always try to improve, to do better.

If the team does not appreciate the work you are doing, the work that testers are doing maybe there is an issue at company level.

Certainly this does not happen at other companies, it may be a company view, maybe you need a change of domain and company.

You could always can switch to different domain in testing and maybe different company.

You could try e-commerce, banking, networking or others.

As an alternative you could try automation for any of the above.

---

@lauda,

> Keep Calm and Continue Testing

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a valid and valuable observation for team dynamics within the SDLC.  The lack of experience indicates the gaps in "opinion/frustration" versus the actual topic/question that should be asked.  In this case the question you are posing is the following:

"How do I constructively increase the value put on "Quality" inside of a development team dynamic, while at the same time increasing my ability to work well in this environment?"

There are a number of factors at play and the first is the most important.

1. How many quality issues currently exist in the product/process?

The goal of QA is to ensure the quality.  The amount of slippage in quality is a direct connection to the importance of the role.  If there are never any issues, find another place as you will not have much value there.  If there are tons of issues, then it is alerting everyone of the issues and proving that the current cycle will not work "successfully" without additional QA activities.

2. How able are you to meet others where they are as well as understanding your own perspective?

You may find 40 issues, but if noone else cares about them including the Product Owner and customers then you need to adjust your perspective.  The point of any job is to be useful, so you need to understand the goal and make your QA observations in support of the end goal.  Being in sync with the Product Owner goal and finding gaps to accomplishing that is where your role fits, so any observations should support an "inadequacy" in the goal of the product (functionality, usability, speed, consistency, 508 compliance, security, etc...)

3. How much pride exists in your team of developers?

I have worked as a developer myself for years and with hundreds of developers from a QA standpoint as well.  Pride of ones work is always there and sometimes hubris in developers.  QA is often seen as the critical poker of pointing out flaws in others artistic genius.  The goal is a "quality product" not individual fulfillment, however in order to achieve a team dynamic every individual must feel needed and appreciated...as your comment indicates you don't feel that which frustrates you.  You need to meet the developer where they are and help them to see how to make a better product.  This may involve you learning some code and understanding the backend terms.  I also recommend a question approach as that gives them the "expert" stance they feel from writing the code.

So instead of saying "this is broken and I can't use this" ask, I think I'm doing this right, but I can't seem to get this to work, is there something I'm doing wrong?  Then you ask what about this and this part seemed like it would confuse users because of x, what do you think?  This will make life so much easier on you as in fact this approach will help you "enable" developers to improve their coding, while at the same time ensuring they still feel good about their work.  Understanding how the application fits together underneath is key to pinpointing the right places to test as well as the right places to ask questions to improve quality.

Lastly I'd say since you mentioned the PO, that the Scrum Master is supposed to ensure all parts are working together, so ensure you are targeting their goals and getting them to say something if it's not working together.  Perhaps that person will have more tips for you.

Good luck and don't give up, but grow into a more team empowering person and SQA individual!

Comment: As a note though, if you don't find value in your own work, you need a job that you do value...my answer is about increasing your SQA ability in a team dynamic as this is a SQA forum.